# eclipse-cdt linker can't find crt0.o

Tags: c, linker, eclipse-cdt, osx-yosemite, eclipse-indigo

I need to get familiar with Eclipse-CDT (indigo) for the first time so created the the project "First" with `first.c` and `first.h`, and then created a static library project `Staticlib` with `mylib.c`.  I
cannot get the projects to link using `Build All` (after cleaning all). The  output is:

```
Building target: First
Invoking: MacOS X C Linker
gcc -static -L"/Users/nate/Eclipse Workspaces/cdtWorkspace/Staticlib/Debug" -L"/Users/nate/Eclipse Workspaces/cdtWorkspace/Staticlib/Release" -o "First"  ./src/first.o   
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
```

Any idea of how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I forgot the in's and out's of *make*.  When I figured out what eclipse-cdt wanted in the make file and the correct syntax it all worked.